# Google Maps Javascript Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to embed a map into an HTML widget and I have got some code which works perfectly. I even understand a little bit of the code as I am a JavaScript newbie.

What I need is to be able to add a hyperlink into the info window for each marker. So if I were to click on say "Australia 1" or "Australia 2" if would open up the appropriate webpage. Just to complicate things I need the equivalent of

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_top">
```

The code I am using works well and is below!

```js
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 700px; float:left;"></div>
<div id="sidebar" style="height: 500px; width: 200px; float: right;"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>

var markers = [];
var map;
var infoWin;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

  infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng( -34.397, 150.644), "Woolongong", "Australia 1", map);
  createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng( -33.9, 151.1), "Sydney", "Australia 2", map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    infoWin.setContent("<h3>"+name+"</h3>"+html);
    infoWin.open(map,marker);
  });
```

Comment: The third parameter to the `createMarker` function is HTML code that will be inserted into the InfoWIndow. Just make this third parameter an anchor element. Here is an example `createMarker(.., ..., "<a href='https://www.example.com' target='_top'>Australia 1</a>", ...);`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Titus. Its probebly me getting the syntax wrong. I have tried   createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng( -34.397, 150.644), "Woolongong", "Australia 1", "<a href='https://www.example.com' target='_top'>Australia 1</a>");   but all that happens is the marker doesn's appear. I really need help with this as its my first week in the Javascript world and I need it spelling out. Cheers, Lambo

Comment: This should work `createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng( -34.397, 150.644), "Woolongong", "<a href='example.com' target='_top'>Australia 1</a>", map);`

Comment: Thanks Titus your a star. I am using wix and the code works perfectly for all types of targets except, you guessed it "Target=_top". This is my fault for using Wix I suppose but I am feeling pretty unlucky at the moment.. Cheers Lambo